# VS2019: The type or namespace name could not be found

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

recently i migrate from vs2017 to vs2019, vs2017 opens and display the documents fine, but vs2019 highlights the namespace red and states The type or namespace name could not be found.

i tried clean and rebuild projects, update "Microsoft.Net.Compilers" and uncheck "parallel project initialization" but non of them works.

Comment: which namespace/dll is not being referenced after migration? Did you verify that all dlls are mapped in project?

Comment: @VishalPawar all projects are referenced properly

Comment: after migraton, you must seen migration report in browser, Did  u saw any errors there?Thay might help you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It was visual studio intellisense problem and following this steps helps me resolve it

1. Clean solution
2. Close visual studio
3. Delete `.suo` file located relatively to source in: `.vs\SolutionName\v16\.suo`
4. Reopen VS and build solution